# How do I only apply css to text inside a button?

Tags: css, button, text, position, css-position

I have this

```html
<button class="jumpButton">"Click me" <svg class="arrowsvg"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7 10L12 15 17 10" aria-hidden="true"></path><svg><button>
```

I want to change the CSS of the "Click me" but changing that also changes the SVG.

```css
.jumpButton #text {

}
```

That doesn't work. I cannot edit the HTML, I want to put the "Click me" to the right of the SVG. I also do not have access to Javascript.

Comment: what CSS you want to apply?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to put "Click me" to the right of the SVG, but right now, the text comes first, then the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the SVG and float it to the left

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

button  {
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="jumpButton">"Click me" <svg class="arrowsvg"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7 10L12 15 17 10" aria-hidden="true"></path><svg><button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you cannot change the html and CSS does not have a selector for the text inside an element that doesn't have a tag around it, I think you need to position the svg with `position: absolute` instead.

```
.jumpButton { 
    position: relative; 
    padding-left: 24px; /* This creates space for the icon */
} 
.arrowsvg { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
}
```

This should accomplish what you are trying to do.
In my tests the svg just takes up a lot of space unnecessarily, which makes the accurate positioning difficult.